# How to get a positive response from recent tag end point of instagram api?

Tags: excel, macros, instagram

I am trying to receive a response from instagram api.
I am keep receiving this response. In between it was working just fine 5days ago.

{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

Here this is my code (I am using excel macro)

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mysearchtag/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx"

objHTTP.Open "Get", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHTTP.send
strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText
```

Can you help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

From the instagram website:

"Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API documentation or the Change Log for more details.

Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 1, 2016. On that date, the app will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process. The previous version of our documentation is still available here."

You will need to go through the app review process again to receive a new API Key, which involves providing a description of the api permissions you need and demonstrating how those permissions are used via a submitted video.

More details on http://instagram.com/developer

Comment: Some of the end-points are still working just fine. I am confused, if there is something i missed in that code above.

Comment: They only work within data from your sandbox users.. (e.g: your data will appear ok.. but public won't until you get your client approved)